# Javascript namespacing/prototype issue

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've been trying to further my understanding of javascript namespacing and prototype inheritance but i am running into an issue.

An example of what i'm dealing with code wise:

```
var namespace = {
    ex1: function () { },
    ex2: function () {
        this.exvar1 = 0,
        this.exvar2 = 0;
    }
}

namespace.ex1.prototype = {
    method1: function () {

    },

    method2: function () {

    }
};

namespace.ex2.prototype = {
    method1: function () {
        alert("ex2.method1" + typeof this.method1);
    },

    method2: function () {
        alert("ex2.method2" + typeof this.method2); 
    }
};
```

if i then try and call a method by doing:

```
namespace.ex2.method1();
```

i find that namespace.ex2.method1 is not a function.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i find that namespace.ex2.method1 is not a function.

Correct. In JavaScript, you don't *directly* assign prototypes to objects (although that's becoming possible as [the new 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) gets adopted; see below). Instead, you set up prototypes on constructor functions which are then assigned to objects constructed by those functions. So if you had done

```
var obj = new namespace.ex2();
obj.method1();
```

...you would have found the method. (Although there's no reason you can't call `namespace.ex2.prototype.method1();` if you want to.)

This indirect approach is somewhat unusual for a prototypical language. ECMAscript 5th edition does introduce a means of creating an object and setting its prototype *directly* (`Object.create`), but that's a fairly new addition to the language.

For more about prototypes, "methods," setting up prototype chains, etc., you might find [this article by Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and [this rather lesser](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) (but perhaps more familiar-sounding, and certainly pragmatic) one by yours truly interesting reading.

Answer (score 0):

create instance before

```
var instance = new namespace.ex1;
```

try here http://jsfiddle.net/quWPC/

Answer (score 0):

Prototypes apply to instances of objects:

```
var foo = function() {};
foo.prototype = {
    a: function() {}
}
var instance = new foo;
instance.a();
```

To put a function directly inside an object (instead of in its prototype), do this:

```
var foo = function() {};
foo.a = function() {};
foo.a();
```